# Creating fill symbols in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fill

Is there a way to create custom fills from a hi res raster format (e.g., png file)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change the `Simple Fill` to `Raster Image Fill` and select the image you would like to use.

[image]